# Getting "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint" when inserting script

Tags: bigcommerce

I'm developing an app, for store fronts and want to get some analytics in checkout. So I want to inject a script in that scope of checkout. When I try to insert it I'm getting "You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint" but I have updated the scopes to checkoutcontent to modify. Not sure what else is wrong

Trying to insert script via an app, getting 403 even though I updated the OAuth scopes to include, Check out content and Checkout

```
    curl --request POST \
      --url https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/{store_hash}/v3/content/scripts \
     --header 'accept: application/json' \
     --header 'content-type: application/json' \
     --header 'x-auth-client: XXXXX' \
     --header 'x-auth-token: XXXXX' \
     --data '{"name":"Test Scripts Tag","description":"Test Scripts Tag","html":"<script src=\\\"https://Somedestination/Test.js\\\"></script>","src":"https://Somedestination/Test.js","auto_uninstall":true,"load_method":"default","location":"footer","visibility":"checkout","kind":"src"}'
```

Getting below error, while expecting a status=200 
status: 403,You don't have a required scope to access the endpoint

Answer (score 0):

The html field shouldn't be included when using src, could you try removing it?

The only errors I was receiving in testing were due to malformed HTML in the html field with the error code 422. It may also be worth trying to create a new API account to rule out scoping causing this.